# java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart cannot be cast to java.lang.String         at NewClass.main(NewClass.java:34)

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-mail, gmail-imap, jtextcomponent

This is the code that is intended to fetch up the email from Gmail server. Along with it also brings the subject and the sender separately. The inbox that i am checking has 5 messages.*(some read and some unread)* 
I wanted the html content to be visible , so i used `JEditorPane`

```
 import javax.mail.*;
 import javax.mail.internet.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

 class NewClass {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.imap.host" , "imap.gmail.com" );
    props.put("mail.imap.user" , "username");
    // User SSL
    props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory" , 993);
    props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.class" , "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory" );
    props.put("mail.imap.port" , 993 );
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props , new Authenticator() {
        @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("username" , "password");
        }
    });

    try {
      Store store = session.getStore("imap");
      store.connect("imap.gmail.com" , "username" , "password");
      Folder fldr = store.getFolder("Inbox");
      fldr.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
      Message msgs[] = fldr.getMessages();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < msgs.length ; i++) {
            // program breaks after the following statement
            System.out.println(InternetAddress.toString(msgs[i].getFrom()) + "<-- FROM" + " " + msgs[i].getSubject() + "<---Subject"); 
            JFrame fr = new JFrame();
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            JEditorPane ep = new JEditorPane("text/html" , (String)msgs[i].getContent());
    ep.setEditable(false);
            JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ep);
            p.add(ep);
            fr.add(p);
            fr.setSize(300,300);
            fr.setVisible(true);
        }
    } catch(Exception exc) {

    }
}
```

}

The output that i get is : 
`Gmail Team <mail-noreply@google.com><-- FROM Get Gmail on your mobile phone<---Subject`

After this output the program gives the following exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at NewClass.main(NewClass.java:34)`.
Why the frame is not visible ?

Comment: Looks like an exception is being thrown. Modify your `catch` block to at least print a stack trace, so you can find out what went wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is here

```
JEditorPane ep = new JEditorPane("text/html" , (String)msgs[i].getContent());
```

you have multipart message `msgs[i].getContent()` returns `javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart`. You can invoke toString on it but correct approach is getting mail parts from it. First you can check by `instanceof MimeMultipart`. Look at [JAVAMAIL API FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#mainbody) how to deal with multipart messages.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `exc.printStackTrace()` in your catch block to see what the problem is.

/e
Your problem is `(String)msgs[i].getContent()`. Try `msgs[i].getContent().toString()`.

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at NewClass.main(NewClass.java:34)`

Answer (score 1):

```
(String)msgs[i].getContent()
```

This perhaps returns a MimeMultiPart object and you are casting it to String.